# Django Form class question

Tags: django

I'm making a form for user registration.  Here's what my template looks like:

```
<h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="/register/" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

And here's my view:

```
from djangoproject1.authentication import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def main(request):
    rform = forms.RegisterForm()
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form': rform})

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rform = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if rform.is_valid():
            print 'VALID!'
            # do something
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/register-success/")
        else:
            print 'INVALID!'
            rform = forms.RegisterForm()
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form': rform})
```

I haven't gotten to the VALID part yet, I'm still working on the invalid part.  Here is what my form looks like:

```
from django import forms

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=6,max_length=15)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(),min_length=6,max_length=15)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(),min_length=6,max_length=15)
    phone_number = forms.RegexField('\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d',error_message='Invalid format')

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password
```

Username, password, phone number.  Pretty straightforward.  However, when I hit "Register" without filling in anything, I should get a bunch of errors but they don't appear anywhere.  Is that supposed to happen automatically or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that in your else you're resetting your form to a new one, and the new form hasn't been validated.  Try removing this line of code from your else

```
rform = forms.RegisterForm()
```

Comment: Yep, if you remove that line, you will return the invalid form, which will contain the error message(s) for the fields that were left empty.

Comment: so does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, ran off for a bit.  Yes that does answer my question, however, I'm still running into an issue.  I'm getting a KeyError exception on "confirm_password".  I looked up KeyError and it says Raised "when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys."  From what I understand about cleaned_data, 'confirm_password' should be in there b/c it's a field but I guess it isnt